# Permalinks don't work on WordPress installation on MAMP.

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mamp

I followed this guide for installing WordPress multisite on MAMP: http://perishablepress.com/wordpress-multisite-mamp/

And it seems to be working fine. I can access WordPress admin, and the site itself. However, whenever I create a page and try to visit it, I get an 404 error, as if the permalink url is broken or something, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Example:

- mysite.domain.local <-- Works
- mysite.domain.local/wp-admin <-- Works
- mysite.domain.local/page1 <-- **Doesn't work, even if I have created the page "Page1"**

My htaccess file looks like this, in accordance with the guide I followed:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: Can you access this `Page1` by `?page_id=xxx` ?

Comment: @bodi0 No that just redirects me to /page1 which is 404 page not found.

Comment: It's weird. Even if I delete the content of my .htaccess file, nothing happens differently. It's like it has no effect. I'm kinda new to editing these hidden files on a Mac via the terminal

Comment: Thank you! I had the .htaccess file under the wrong folder. After moving it to the root folder everything started to work correctly. If you write an answer regarding this I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove your custom-edit from your `.htaccess` file and edit the `permalinks` settings (i.e. revert to default), save the changes.  This way `Wordpress` will be forced to re-generate it (if it has any errors) and everything should work.

This `.htaccess` file should be located in `root` of your `Wordpress` installation (you may have other `.htaccess` files in sub-folders as well).

Answer (score 1):

Just go to Wordpress admin page,

then Click on Settings > Permalinks,

Then Click Save Changes.

This will be fixed.

Comment: Nothing happened. Still "Page is not found"

Comment: Check as @bodi0 suggests, "Can you access this Page1 by ?page_id=xxx ". Because if this works then we can fix by resetting .htaccess file

Comment: No that only redirected me to /page1 which is 404 not found.

Comment: Try to change the Permalink Structure in Wordpress admin, Settings > permalinks to "/%postname%/" and then click Save Changes.